# How to Calculate a Wave Travelling Along the Circumference of a Circle?

Tags: circles, wave-equation, wavelets

I'm wondering how you might calculate a wave that traverses the circumference of a circle. This image is a terribly drawn attempt at showing what I mean,

[image]

Imagine that the black wavy pattern is a perfect sine wave; how would you calculate it so that it runs in a circle like the above?

Comment: You can describe it with a polar equation. See [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d5ooe7rmgs).

Comment: @K.defaoite Wonderfully simple! Thank you.